# How to read android:layout_height from style resource in custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am building a custom `View` that contains two standard Views. I have a default style for each contained View, and a custom attribute that lets the user specify a custom style for each contained View. I can get the default *vs.* custom styles just fine, and pass the right style id as the third parameter of each contained View's constructor. What I am having a hard time doing is generating a `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` for these contained Views, based on the `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` in the appropriate style.

It *seems* like I need to use the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams(Context, AttributeSet)` constructor, and the [AttributeSet docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) say that I should get an `AttributeSet` *via*

```
XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(myResouce);  
AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
```

... but that throws a `Resources$NotFoundException` with a warning from `frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp` that `Requesting resource %p failed because it is complex`.

Hence, my questions, in decreasing order of specificity:

1. Is there a way to get an `XmlPullParser` that works with "complex" elements?
2. Is there some other way to get an `AttributeSet` that corresponds to a `<style>` element?
3. Is there some other way to construct a `LayoutParameters` that will pay attention to the `layout_height` and `layout_width` values in a given style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    static ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutFromStyle(Context context,
        int style) {
      TypedArray t = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
              null,
              new int[] { android.R.attr.layout_width,
                      android.R.attr.layout_height }, style, style);
      try {
          int w = t
                  .getLayoutDimension(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          int h = t
                  .getLayoutDimension(1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          return new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(w, h);
      } finally {
          t.recycle();
      }
    }
```